# How i can login in my application jquery method post

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with login in my application.
When I try login I see this error :

```
"error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert('POST failed.');"
```

I don't know why it is doing that.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
      $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#loginForm").on("submit",function(e) {
        $("#submitButton",this).attr("disabled","disabled");
            var u = $("#username", this).val();
            var p = $("#password", this).val();
            if(u != '' && p!= '') {
                var LoginUserModel = {
                            Login: u,
                            Password: p
                        }
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 
                         /login",  
                        dataType: "json",
                        crossDomain: true,                  
                        data: LoginUserModel,

                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            console.log(data);
                             if (data) {
                                console.log('elo');
                            }
                            else{
                                navigator.notification.alert("Your login failed", function() {});
                                console.log('nie');
                                }
                            $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
                            console.log('elo');
                        },
                        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert('POST failed.');
                                }
                    });
            }

          });
          });
      </script>
```

Someone know what is the problem because I don't have any idea. Why I can't login in the application?
Thanks

Comment: start by inspecting the actual request in browser  dev tools network tab. Inspect data sent/returned, status etc. Need more debugging feedback to start isloating where the problem lies. Also you aren't preventing the default form submit

Comment: If this isn't a copy/paste error, you are missing an opening quotation on `/login"`. If your app is actually outputting code, it is usually going to be some missing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add opening quotation on /login"
2. Set contentType: "application/json"
3. Set data: JSON.stringify(LoginUserModel)

After making this change, look at network/console tab in browser developer tools.